# CSS /JavaScript. Giving value to the same attribute

Tags: javascript, css

There is a `div` for example. If `width` value is defined using JavaScript as `value1`, and the same width value in CSS is defined as `value2` (`value1 != value2`), which value will `div` get for the `width` in the end?

Comment: Try it and find out!

Comment: @jedifans 1+ for comment of the day

Comment: Code is worth 1024 words (or should that be 512?). Not least because *"If `width` value is defined using JavaScript as `value1`"* can mean at *least* three different things.

Comment: @jedifans +1 from me too

Comment: @jedifans: While that will work, it will miss nuance like what happens with `!important` properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is unclear, but style properties defined on the element itself (e.g., in its `style` attribute or via its `style` property, which is a structured reflection of that attribute), aka "inline styles," take precedence over CSS rules **unless** those CSS rules are marked `!important`. If the inline style *also* has `!important`, it wins. (Note that you can't set `!important` rules via the properties on the `style` structured reflected property; you have to either set the attribute or set the property's `cssText` property to completely replace the inline style.)

So:

```js
document.querySelector(".ex1").style.width = "200px";
document.querySelector(".ex2").style.width = "200px";
document.querySelector(".ex3").setAttribute("style", "width: 200px !important");
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.ex1 {
  width: 300px;
}
.ex2 {
  width: 300px !important;
}
.ex3 {
  width: 300px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1">200px (inline wins)</div>
<div class="ex2">300px (CSS wins)</div>
<div class="ex3">200px (inline wins again)</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [**Specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of CSS.

When you will using javascript the style will be added as inline style unless you are adding it as a class.

> Inline styles added to an element (e.g., style="font-weight:bold")
>   always overwrite any styles in external stylesheets and thus can be
>   thought of as having the highest specificity.

So value defined using js will overwrite the value defined in css file

Answer (score 0):

As CSS applies in cascade, it will depend on which element you load last.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript add style to element as inline and inline style has higher priority than css.So, javascript defined properties(width) are applicable for div. But if you defined "!important" in css than div set the properties according to css.

Find the below demo:

Create file demo.css and paste below code:

```
 #test1{
 background-color: green;
 width: 100px ;
 }
#test2{
background-color: green;
width: 100px !important;
 }
```

create html file and paste below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Title</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css">
  </head>
<body> 
  <div id="test1">
   test1
  </div>
  <div id="test2">
   test2
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  document.getElementById("test1").style.width="200px";
  document.getElementById("test2").style.width="200px";
</script>
</html>
```